# Will list append create a copy?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am newbie to python. I came across this code.

```
simple_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dict_list = []
for x in simple_list:
    local_dict = {'key': x}
    dict_list.append(local_dict)
print(dict_list)
```

The for loop creates a dictionary for each element in the list `simple_list` and then append the newly created dictionary to another list `dict_list`.

My question is related to append function. We have a local variable called `local_dict` inside the for loop. When we call append, will it copy `local_dict`? or create a reference?

I assume that it would copy `local_dict` because that variable will go out of scope after the for loop.
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't read the [names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) article yet. You should read that - it should clear up some of the confusion you're having about how Python objects and variables relate to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The scope is not changing here as you use a loop (not a function).

You code will create a reference, but only to the last dictionary of the list since the name is reused in the loop:

```
simple_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dict_list = []
for x in simple_list:
    local_dict = {'key': x}       # creating a new dictionary
    dict_list.append(local_dict)

print(dict_list)

local_dict['NEW'] = 'D'           # reusing the last created dictionary
print(dict_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'key': 'a'}, {'key': 'b'}, {'key': 'c'}]
[{'key': 'a'}, {'key': 'b'}, {'key': 'c', 'NEW': 'D'}]
```

If you were to use `local_dict` in several lists, then there would be shared references as well:

```
simple_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dict_list = []
dict_list2 = []
for x in simple_list:
    local_dict = {'key': x}
    dict_list.append(local_dict)
    dict_list2.append(local_dict)

print(dict_list)

dict_list2[0]['NEW'] = 'new1'
dict_list2[1]['NEW'] = 'new2'
print(dict_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'key': 'a'}, {'key': 'b'}, {'key': 'c'}]
[{'key': 'a', 'NEW': 'new1'}, {'key': 'b', 'NEW': 'new2'}, {'key': 'c'}]
```

Comment: Worth mentioning, that you should be careful with that, as you might get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'local_dict' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @sudden_appearance you can get a `NameError` if `simple_list` is empty, `UnboundLocalError` would require a different scope (which isn't the case here).